# Filter Data between two Persian date in c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, filter, comparison-operators, persian-calendar

Hi I want to filter my data which is between two Persian date.
Note: Persian date is a string data type like : "1400/02/23"
when I want to filter my table in SQL Server I simply write like the code bellow:

```
 SELECT * FROM Table
 WHERE Date >="1400/01/02" AND Date <="1400/05/10"
```

but in C# syntax I do not know how to fetch date between two string to use in my filter back-end code. If I simply compare the error raise that string type data can not use comparison operator.
I would be glad and grateful if somebody help me

Comment: That's an invalid query to begin with. `"` in SQL (not just SQL Server) is used to quote object names, eg table names. To avoid localization issues you should use  date literals in the `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YYYYMMDD` format, eg `BETWEEN '14000102` and '14000510'` BUT a *far* better solution would be to use parameterized queries and pass the dates as actual date-typed parameters in code

Comment: In C# you could try `DateTime.Parse` with a suitable culture setting. See the article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=net-6.0)

Comment: `date is a string data type` that's a major design bug. Use a proper date type instead, eg `date` or `datetime2`. Storing strings means you have no idea what is actually stored in that field, what the format is or even what the order of the elements is. In C# use the appropriate type, `DateTime`

Comment: thank you @PanagiotisKanavos I'm not designer of database I just only use it and I think I use your advice I mean use date in YYYYMMDD format

Answer (score 1):

First, convert Persian Date to Gregorian date and then do the comparison.